# How do reduce transaction log growth for batched nvarchar(max) updates

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, transactions, sqltransaction

Our app needs to add large amounts of text to SQL Server 2005 database (up to 1 GB for a single record). For performance reasons, this is done in chunks, by making a stored procedure call for each chunk (say, usp_AddChunk). usp_AddChunk does not have any explicit transactions.

What I'm seeing is that reducing the chunk size from 100MB to 10MB results in massively larger transaction logs. I've been told this is because each time usp_AddChunk is called, an "implicit" (my term) transaction will log all of the existing text. So, for a 150MB record:

100MB chunk size: 100 (0 bytes logged) + 50 (100 MB logged) = 100 MB logged

will be smaller than

10 MB chunk size: 10 (0 bytes logged) + 10 (10 MB logged) + 10 (20 MB logged) ... + 10 (140 MB logged) = 1050 MB logged

I thought that by opening a transaction in my C# code (before I add the first chunk, and commit after the last chunk), this "implicit" transaction would not happen, and I could avoid the huge log files. But my tests show the transaction log growing 5x bigger using the ADO.NET transaction.

I won't post the code, but here's a few details:

1. I call SqlConnection.BeginTransaction()
2. I use a different SqlCommand for each chunk
3. I assign the SqlTransaction from (1) to each SqlCommand
4. I usually close the connection after each SqlCommand execution, but I've also tried not closing the connection with the same results

What's the flaw in this scheme? Let me know if you need more info. Thanks!

Note: using a simple or bulk-logged recovery model is not an option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by 'chunks' you mean something like:

```
UPDATE table
SET blob = blob + @chunk
WHERE key = @key;
```

Then you are right that the operation is fully logged. You should follow the [BLOB usage guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1904w6t(VS.80).aspx) and use the .Write methods for chuncked updates:

```
UPDATE table
SET blob.Write(@chunk, NULL, NULL)
WHERE key = @key;
```

This will minimally log the update (if possible, see [Operations That Can Be Minimally Logged](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191244.aspx)):

> The UPDATE statement is fully logged;
>   however, partial updates to large
>   value data types using the .WRITE
>   clause are minimally logged.

Not only that this is minimally logged, but because the update is an explicit write at the end of the BLOB, the engine will know that you only updated a portion of the BLOB and will only log *that*. When you update with `SET blob=blob+@chunk` te engine will see that the entire BLOB has received a new value and won't detect the fact that you really only changed the BLOB by appending new data, so the it will log the entire BLOB (several times, as you already found out).

BTW you should use chunks of size multiple of 8040:

> For best performance, we recommend
>   that data be inserted or updated in
>   chunk sizes that are multiples of 8040
>   bytes.

Comment: BTW, in full logged model you'll still see the log size reduction when using .WRITE just from the fact that the engine understands that you're doing a partial update and not an entire BLOB column update.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. Unfortunately--which I neglected to mention--the column is actually XML (a big blob of text wrapped in XML tags), and .WRITE doesn't work for XML columns.

Comment: Each individual chunk is valid XML then? You can try column.modify, using XML X-Query insert to append the chunks, but I'm not sure how that works in regard to log space. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175466.aspx

Comment: Not only you omitted to mention is XML, you said in the title is nvarchar(max) lol :) Anyway, it was actualy useful exercise for me to digg up all the info on chunked updates and I may make use in a project soon of what I learned.

Comment: The chunks are submitted as nvarchar(max), but the chunks are appended to the XML blob: <xml>[chunk1]</xml>…<xml>[chunk1][chunk2]</xml>…etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you may have to do is surround each "chunk" or group of chunks with it's own transaction and commit after each group.  Surrounding the entire thing with your own ADO transaction is essentially doing the same thing as the implicit transaction does, so that won't help.  You have to commit in smaller chunks to keep the log smaller.